# Why do angularjs controller declaration have this syntax structure?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I see the following angularjs controller syntax structure all the time.

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController', 
['$scope', '$interval', '$location', 
function ($scope, $interval, $location)
{
}]);
```

Why the repetition in the parameter names? Why not just like this

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController', 
    ['$scope', '$interval', '$location', 
    function ()
    {
    }]);
```

or

```
   angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController', 
    [ 
    function ($scope, $interval, $location)
    {
    }]);
```

Comment: Cos if you don't have them inside the function you cannot use them and angular cannot know which dependencies you are talking about as it cannot get the parameters set for a function. They do both because they have too.

Comment: you can able to use last option as well like this : `angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController',function($scope, $interval, $location){});`

Comment: @gillesc : agree, you need to create object which you want to use as a function's parameter, because your code is inside your controller's function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dependency injection in Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836414/dependency-injection-in-angular-js)

Comment: So it would not work for production unless for some reason the JS wasn't served minified :) Still feel like the result is nearly the same, if anything it's dangerous that it work when not minified which might be what dev are working with when prod build script probably minify JS. Also make me want to dig in their code as I'm aware of `arguments` but not sure how they extract the name of each argument to pass in the correct dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The array syntax will help you with minification/uglify of your `js` code.

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController', 
  function ($scope, $interval, $location) {
    // code here
});
```

Will be minified and mangled as:

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController', 
 function (a, b, c) {
    // code here
});
```

So Angular won't be able to figure out which dependencies to inject

On the other hand, using the `array` declaration:

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController', 
 ['$scope', '$interval', '$location', function ($scope, $interval, $location) {
    // code here
}]);
```

Will be minified as :

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController', 
  ['$scope', '$interval', '$location', function (a, b, c) {
    // code here
}]);
```

So Angular will know what `a`, `b` and `c` represent.

---

There's also another way to inject variables if you use your first example code like below:

```
WorkoutController.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval', '$location'];
```

or

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController', /* @ngInject */
  function ($scope, $interval, $location) {
   // code here
});
```

which will create the `$inject` method mentioned above when the code is annotated.

---

So, there are mainly four kinds of [annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation):

1. [Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation)  - the first example code
2. [Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation)  - the second example code
3. [$inject Property Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation)  - the $inject method
4. $ngInject Comment Annotation  - the [@ngInject](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate#explicit-annotations-with-nginject) method

---

### ng-annotate

Tools like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) let you use implicit dependency annotations in your app and automatically add inline array annotations prior to minifying. If you decide to take this approach, you probably want to use `ng-strict-di`.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using Strict Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection).

Comment: Is `$ngInject` a typo?

Answer (score 2):

This "repetion" is to make it safe for minification:

[AngularJS - Controllers, Dependencies, and Minification](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/13/angularjs-controllers-dependencies-and-minification.aspx)

Comment: If one doesn't care about the minification, how would a controller declaration look like?

Answer (score 2):

or you can use following syntax, according to popular angular-styleguide https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

```
angular.module('7minWorkout')
       .controller('WorkoutController', WorkoutController);
WorkoutController.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval', '$location'];

function WorkoutController($scope, $interval, $location) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write the first version since it just omits the parameters of the function which are also accesible via `arguments` inside the function. So you would avoid the repition but slicing the arguments property is also not really efficient (compared to just type out the parameters).

As the others answers stated the repition is to make it safe for minification.

Answer (score 2):

The first controller syntax makes it possible to minify/uglify the javascript code with the use of tools like ngmin. I'm not quite sure if the 2nd and 3rd options you have provided are viable options to create a controller, but in any case they will not be minified correctly since the tools will not now what the providers are. I would either suggest to use option 1 or option 3 (without the brackets) to create a controller. Note that option 3 will not be minified correctly by automated tools.

Some Useful information about creating controllers:
[AngularJS Developer Guide - Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

**option3 without brackets**

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController', function ($scope, $interval, $location)
    {
      //Your Code
    });
```