# which is the difference, inject dependency?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization

Hello I want to know the differences, between this syntax

```
app.controller('demoCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {
  //code
}])
```

And this syntax

```
app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope, $resource) {
  //code
})
```

Which one is better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do angularjs controller declaration have this syntax structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852967/why-do-angularjs-controller-declaration-have-this-syntax-structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first syntax is called "inline array notation" and is used to declare the dependencies so that during code minification the dependencies are properly injected. During code minification, `function($scope, $resource)` could become something like `function(a, b)` and if you use the second syntax (implicit annotation) the injector will not be able to find the dependencies because it will be searching for `a` and `b`, not `$scope` and `$resource`. However, if you use the first syntax and your code is minified, the injector will be able to find and inject the dependencies with no problems.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation for more information.